# Examples of learning via exactly integrable gradient flows

Tags: machine-learning, lg.learning, st.statistics

If $\ell (\vec{w}, \vec{z})$ is the loss function at weights $\vec{w}$ and for data $\vec{z}$ then corresponding to a distribution ${\cal D}$ we can consider doing gradient flow with step-length $\eta >0$ to solve the corresponding risk minimization question,

$$\frac{d \vec{w}}{dt} = -\eta \cdot \frac{\partial }{\partial \vec{w}} \mathbb{E}_{\vec{z} \sim {\cal D}} [\ell (\vec{w}, \vec{z}) ]$$

- Are there non-trivial examples of this for which the above ODE is exactly integrable and the risk gets minimized as $t \rightarrow \infty$ along the solution?

Answer (score 1):

How about the simple squared loss function used in linear regression? That is, let $\ell(w(t), z) = \frac{1}{2n} \sum_{i=1}^n (z_i^\top w(t) - y_i)^2$ for data vectors $z_i \in \mathbb{R}^d$ and $y\in \mathbb{R}^n$?

For the sake of this answer, I'll use the shorthand notation $Z \in \mathbb{R}^{d\times n}$, where each column of $Z$ is the vector $z_i \in \mathbb{R}^d$.

If you use this as the loss function, then the given differential equation is $$\frac{dw(t)}{dt} = -\eta (ZZ^\top) w(t) + Z y.$$ I think this can be solved to get the solution you seek, and I explain below.

Suppose $Z$ is rank-$n$, and let $Z = \sum_{i = 1}^n s_i u_i v_i^\top$ be its singular value decomposition. Pre-multiplying the given ODE with any of the $u_i$ vectors yields the ODE $$ \frac{d}{dt} (u_i^\top w(t)) = - \frac{1}{n} s_i^2 u_i^\top w(t) + \frac{1}{n} s_i v_i^\top y.$$ This is a standard first-order constant coefficient ODE and can be solved  by, for instance, the method of integrating factors. Applying this technique gives $$ u_i^\top w(t) = \frac{1}{s_i} v_i^\top y + c_i (\frac{s_i}{n} v_i^\top y) e^{-\frac{s_i^2 t}{n}}, $$ where $c_i$ is a constant of integration. If you are given an initial condition, you can use it to obtain $c_i$. Suppose you have $w_0 = 0$. Then, this initial condition results in the rule $$u_i^\top w(t) = \frac{1}{s_i} (v_i^\top y) (1 - e^{-s_i^2 t/ n}), $$ for all $i \in [n]$. Therefore, as $t\rightarrow \infty$, we have for all $i \in [n]$ that $u_i^\top w(t) \rightarrow \frac{1}{s_i} v_i^\top y$. This means the loss $\ell(w_t, z) \rightarrow 0$, as you require.

Comment: Thanks :) By "non-trivial" I really meant that the predictor not be a linear function in the weights that one is training over. I think I can construct also an example where the predictor is a quadratic function of the weights but thats about it. And even with quadratics I am not sure that I can deal with say a predictor of the kind, $f(\vec{w},\vec{z}) = \langle \vec{w}, \vec{z} \rangle ^2$. This already looks unclear to me...